# What is the penalty for using vias?

Tags: pcb-design

What is the penalty for using vias in PCB design regarding impedance, capacitance and EMI?

To make the question more specific:
Let's assume that the PCB is going to be used for an 8-bit computer with Vcc at 5 V. Is it safe to have a clock line (~4 MHz) through 5 vias compared to no vias at all?

Comment: 8-bit computer, but at what frequency? I would assume a 10GHz computer would have tighter requirements on timing than a 10kHz one.

Comment: Good question, edited the question to include a frequency on 4 MHz :-)

Comment: Look up via inductance or via capacitance, did you know that every physical object has inductance, capacitance and resistance? Everything is a filter, an electrical engineers job is to figure out if its a problem at the frequency they are using. Under 50Mhz pcb parasitic's are minimal.

Comment: Why do you have this concern? At 4MHz almost nothing matters, vias, flywires, nothing. Do you mean XTAL does not work? This would be a different angle. Post your real question.

Comment: 4MHz is almost DC. You need to do a really bad pcb to face signal integrity issues.

Comment: I am currently designing the PCB for my homebrew Z80 computer and just wanted to know if there are any penalties for using ex. 5 vias versus none vias. My concern is that I receive unstable boards and have to redo it all over again. Googling for penalty/cost for vias in PCBs doesn't give the answer and it seems like a good question for this page.

Comment: Some of these comments seems like good answer on my question, i.e. at 4 MHz there are almost no penalty at all. No need to be harsh.

Comment: @Ali Chen: real question? I'm not trying to get help with my job or homework. Questions and answers should be useful for everybody, not just me.

Comment: More vias increases your PWB manufacturing cost. If you're very cost-sensitive and manufacturing very high volumes, you might even notice.

Comment: vias are good and bad.  Good if the path to a grnd/power plane is shorter bad if it adds inductance to a critical high speed clock or for power and U dont have decoupling cap for power.  Good if you do. If you use 3 microvias instead it means 1/3 the ESL. .  4x Multilayer boards usually cost according to copper total weight and not thruholes and microvias are cheap. Good if it reduces the loop area with surge cap current, bad if you dont know what controlled impedance means.

Comment: "it depends".  Of course the rise/fall time is more important than the clock frequency, but I'd wager you'd be fine. You could place a series place holder resistor near the driver. Fitting it with a resistors later (instead of a 0 ohm link) can slow down the edges.

Comment: "Fancier", especially long paths may induce noise due to external EMI - regardless of underlying line frequency, producing e.g. false edges where there should be none. Although I have no idea how vias specifically may influence that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this frequency, as several people said in comments, 5 vias is not a problem.

The problem could be:

- mismatching impedance between output of clock and inputs connected to the clock line. For this you can use series resistor of about 50-100 Ohms as close to the *source* of clock as possible;
- too high fan-out. You must ensure that under no circumstance clock signal is being overloaded, causing its shape to deteriorate, and thus causing clocking malfunction or false positives. Buffer clock signal within the circuit;
- type of output for the clock. I would choose to have HC or HCU chip generating the clock to ensure the signal is almost rail-to-rail (in contrast with TTL logic which could be 0.4 V to 3 V).

It seems your question is caused by higher-order issue, and you say

> My concern is that I receive unstable boards and have to redo it all over again.

and the clock signal, while most vital for the circuit, may not be the cause of instability. Small timing violation of the read, write, memory or I/O request lines relative to each other or relative to clock may cause malfunction. Example: I was dealing with malfunctioning i8255, and it turned out that /CS should be removed after /RD or /WR are deactivated. Deactivating /CS with read/write signal causes chip not to latch data properly.

Comment: Great, thank you :-) The question could be applied for all lines but I picked the clock line as an example because it is the one that switches the most. The fan-out shouldn't be a problem since I have verified it and I also uses buffers on the most loaded lines (I use LS-TTL btw.). I have also verified the timing and everything should be fine. I will look into the resistor suggestion :-)

Comment: If you have scope I propose using it to check shape of the signal in various locations of the circuit. Making unproven fixes may slightly mitigate the problem, but it may pop up again under harsher circumstances, and in times when they are least desired.

Comment: Yes, I have a scope, which I used to debug the computer when it was made with low quality breadboards :-) Very useful, but unfortunately I do not have any PCB I can perform experiments on (yet).

Answer (score 0):

If I may be somewhat strict (4Mhz is not really that big of a deal) in this matter. Unless all other traces are carrying higher frequencies I would not have a "high energy" signal like this going through 5 via's. That is not a good design. Try and prioritize the signals that contains most energy so that they have a better trace to its destination.

Of course, if the design is final and if the via's are sufficient in size and the board is "normal" in design without any extraordinary properties, then there is no problem with having the design as it is. It will work.